# Which will have more faster for backups between usb drive on vm or NAS drive

Tags: backup, storage, network-attached-storage, truenas, ibm-xseries

I have `IBM server` with `SAS` drives and `ESXi Server` with `many VM` (not production).

Now for backups of VM i have two options

1. But NAS drive and use that on network
2. Get USB drive , attach to `FreeNAS VM on Esxi server` and then backup there

I want to know which one will have faster speed

Nework speed is 1GBps and usb is 2.0.
But i am thinking of using usb3.0 Pcie card

Its my home lab only not prod and by NAS i mean network drive avaiable in market single disk only

Comment: As is usually the case, **it depends**.  But my **broad guess**, which may be completely wrong for your particular environment and workload, is that the NAS will be quite a lot faster, especially if it's a multi-spindle NAS.  Get them both, and test; or get the USB drive, which will be cheap, and see if it's fast enough for your needs.

Comment: This will to some extent depend upon the speed of your network and the speed of your USB port - neither of which you told us.

Comment: I have added the details

Comment: If this is a lab then why don't you just erm use the lab and test it? Also please read [about] and note the exclusions.

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022290 - `It is not possible to utilize a USB 3.0 device connected to the physical host; the device will be ignored`.  So you will be limited to USB 2.0 performance.

Comment: @Zoredache well not really, since he wants to back up VMs the backup software will also run in a VM and not in the ESXi host kernel, thus client-connected USB passthrough will be used which supports USB 3.

Comment: @RealityExtractor, The statement client connected means is referring to a connection **via the vsphere client**.  You can't run the vsphere client on an ESXi host, and he seemed to want to have the USB drive connected to the ESXI host.  So what he is describing is NOT client connected.

Comment: @Zoredache so he did, it says right there to attach USB to FreeNAS, missed it, thanks, will update answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sweeping generalization: USB 2 will be slower than a single physical drive on the network, USB 3 will be significantly faster than a single physical drive on the network.

Having said that, the real answer is that it depends.
If you have an array of drives as your network target then it's possible to saturate a 1 GbE network link and your network target will be faster.

Other than that, if these are not production VMs then I would save myself the effort of backing them up at all.

**UPDATE:** As @Zoredache pointed out, vSphere currently (May 2014, v 5.5) doesn't support USB 3.0 pass-through so backing up via the network will undoubtedly be faster than to a USB 2.0 drive that's attached to the FreeNAS VM via pass-through.